# ushare doesn't like the fact that eth0 is down even though I am using wlan0

Tags: upnp, dlna

I'm trying to use ushare to share my music collection with my Xbox.

I am using the following command line:

```
ushare -i wlan0 -x -c ~/Music/
```

But I get the following as an error:

```
Interface eth0 is down.
Recheck uShare's configuration and try again !
ioctl: Cannot assign requested address
```

I have an ethernet adapter in my PC but it's not connected. How can I get it to be happy with wlan0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer this one (i hope):

ushare needs to run as root (maybe not, see commments)

1. Rather than starting it with the
   command you've mentioned, try doing
   this:

   ```
   sudo service ushare start
   ```

   after you've set all of the options
   in the configuration file.

   The configuration the error message
   is mentioning is located at
   `/etc/ushare.conf` (or perhaps
   `/etc/ushare/ushare.conf` I'm not
   sure). In it, you'll be able to set
   the network interface permanently.

   These are the relevant bits:

   ```
   # Interface to listen to (default is eth0).
   # Ex : USHARE_IFACE=eth1
   USHARE_IFACE=wlan0


   # Directories to be shared (space or CSV list).
   # Ex: USHARE_DIR=/dir1,/dir2
   USHARE_DIR=/home/rich/Music
   ```

   Two things additionally: I don't
   know what `-x` and `-c` do, i hope
   there's an option for it in the
   configuration. Secondly, the
   directories in USHARE_DIR might have
   to be absolute path (i.e. not ~ but
   /home/rich or whatever your user
   name is).
2. If all of this doesn't work
   properly, or if you just don't want to try it out, you can also just run your
   command prepending `sudo`.

Note: my sources for ushare needing to be ran as root are all either concerning different Linux distribution or they are rather old. If this is no longer the case, please let me know - I don't want to send anybody down the wrong path.

Comment: uShare runs fine in the user context. No need to be root. +1 for pointing to ushare.conf. Once the config is set up jus run `ushare -c/share` with optional parameter `-x` for XBox. See http://ushare.geexbox.org/#Usage

Comment: -x is for saying "behave badly so that you work with the Xbox" and -c tells it which folder to share...

Comment: To get my Xbox360 to see the uShare, I had to do the above and also set USHARE_ENABLE_XBOX=yes but USHARE_ENABLE_DLNA to blank (not 'yes' as some tutorials suggest).  FYI: you can get to a GUI wizard with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ushare`

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually change the configuration by editing the file

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/ushare.conf
```

and changing

```
USHARE_IFACE=eth0
```

to

```
USHARE_IFACE=wlan0
```